# How to transfer data from root user to other user (Kali linux)

Tags: linux, debian, root, data-transfer

I am running Kali Rolling. I had a very bad habit of using the root user for everything (downloading packages, downloading files, transferring photos, and customizing Kali (the clock and icons and window and shell layout in the tweak tool) etc.)

Is there any way I can migrate ALL of the things mentioned above to my other user, and delete it from the root user? Basically I want to make ideal (or good enough) clone of the account, but without the root privileges, then clean up the original root account to avoid taking up unnecessary space

Answer (score 1):

`mv` (or `cp`, if you must) files to new home directory, `chown` to new user, done.